# How to make alert before show error page?

Tags: laravel

I have some database and one of the tables have attribute is ID_teknisi with a unique key. And I'm trying to check if I include with the same value, and show an error page. So I want before the error page show an alert on this page.

I used Laravel, and MySQL, language PHP.

I've coded in the controller in Laravel.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = new ModelTeknisi();
        if ($data->ID_teknisi==$request->ID_teknisi){
            return alert('ID Teknisi sudah ada!');history.go(-1); 
        } else {
        $data->ID_teknisi = $request->ID_teknisi;
        $data->nama_lengkap = $request->nama_lengkap;
        $data->no_hp = $request->no_hp;
        $data->password = $request->password;
        $data->re_password = $request->re_password;
        $data->save();
            return redirect()->route('teknisi.index')->with('alert-success','Berhasil Menambahkan Data!');
        }
    }
```

I expect that will show the alert. But show the error.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException thrown with message
>   "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'SHU27HSY' for key 'ID_teknisi' (SQL: insert into `acc_teknisi`
>   (`ID_teknisi`, `nama_lengkap`, `no_hp`, `password`, `re_password`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (SHU27HSY, Elang Bayu,
>   081234037169, halo, halo, 2019-07-17 02:38:53, 2019-07-17 02:38:53))"

Answer (score 0):

you can check this from documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'ID_teknisi' => 'required|unique:acc_teknisi,ID_teknisi'
    ];
}
```

and also make validation for all fields
and in your blade file in form

```
@if($errors->has('ID_teknisi'))
 {{$errors->first('email');}}
@endif
```

Plz,see how to do validation on requests first then code your example

Answer (score 0):

As the error describing the supplied value to `ID_teknisi` already exists. So you have to check the unique value every time before inserting into the database.

As per your method, you are applying the javascript into the PHP, which is not the right way.

```
$data = new ModelTeknisi();
if ($data->ID_teknisi==$request->ID_teknisi){
    return alert('ID Teknisi sudah ada!');history.go(-1); 
}
```

**You can achieve it by slightly modify your method.**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // First check if the value should be unique
    $request->validate([
        'ID_teknisi' => 'required|unique:acc_teknisi,ID_teknisi'
    ], [
        'ID_teknisi.unique' => 'ID Teknisi sudah ada!'
    ]);


    $data = new ModelTeknisi();

    $data->ID_teknisi = $request->ID_teknisi;
    $data->nama_lengkap = $request->nama_lengkap;
    $data->no_hp = $request->no_hp;
    $data->password = $request->password;
    $data->re_password = $request->re_password;
    $data->save();

    return redirect()->route('teknisi.index')
         ->with('alert-success','Berhasil Menambahkan Data!');

}
```

And add the following code on your blade template.

```
@if($errors->has('ID_teknisi'))
    <script>alert({{ $errors->first('ID_teknisi') }});</script>
@endif
```

If you are using an older version of Laravel then you can achieve it by https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#manually-creating-validators